# More efficient way to go between two html5 audio tracks via jquery

Tags: jquery, html5-audio

I have the following code which goes  back and forth between two audio tracks.  But I have a feeling that the 2 functions can be reduced to a single one that can toggle the 2 audio tracks...

```
function addEventHandlers() {

                $('a.next').toggle(function () {
                tracka();
                },
                function () {
                  trackb();

                });
            }

            function tracka() {
                audio.trigger('pause');
                audio.prop("currentTime", 0);
                var mtrack = "ItstheMostWonderfulTimeoftheYear.mp3";
                audio.prop("src", "audio/"+mtrack);
                audio.trigger('play');
            }

            function trackb() {
                audio.trigger('pause');
                audio.prop("currentTime", 0);
                var mtrack = "winterWonderland.mp3";
                audio.prop("src", "audio/" + mtrack);
                audio.trigger('play');
            }
```

Is there a more efficient way to reduce the 2 functions to a single function?

Answer (score 0):

You could always toggle src property. You would need to extend the jquery.

**jQuery extension:**

```
$.fn.togglePropValue = function (name, vals) {
    var toggles = vals.split(' ');
    if (toggles.length > 1) {
        if (this.prop(name) == toggles[0]) {
            this.prop(name, toggles[1]);
        } else if (this.prop(name) == toggles[1])

        {
            this.prop(name, toggles[0]);
        }
    }
    return this;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$('#toggleSong').click(function () {
    $('#audio1').togglePropValue('src', 'http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Commercial%20DEMO%20-%2007.mp3 http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Commercial%20DEMO%20-%2009.mp3').trigger('play');
});
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/1d9q0fhx/